# How to support directive for number and text as well for input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a directive to check if input value is number or not and according to perform action

```
myApp.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                function fromUser(text) {

                    if (text) {
                        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
                        if (transformedInput !== text) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                    return undefined;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            }
        };
    });
```

this above code will work when i will use `<input type="text"/>` but when i will use `<input type="number"/>` the above code will stop the work.

Please tell me how to support both ?

Comment: yes because `.replace` is the method for `strings`

Comment: can u create a simple fiddle?

Comment: you are dealing with numbers not strings. Why would you need this in the first place when browser already filters out non numeric characters?

Comment: @charlietfl I have to deal with both number/string in tht case what will be solution

Comment: what do you want to achieve? NOTE that if you use `input type="number"` than only permitted values other than digits are are `+,-,.,e,E`

Comment: solution for what? You haven't explained a problem with number input. Note you can always use conditional based on attr.type

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code which has one more condition(isNaN) in 'if' as below,

```
myApp.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {

                if (text && isNaN(text)) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Suppose if number is coming how to work this code with number as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below code fixed my issue

```
myapp.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                function fromUser(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        if(!isNaN(value)){
                        var text = value.toString();
                      }
                      else{
                        var text = value;
                      }
                        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
                        if (transformedInput !== text) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                    return undefined;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            }
        };
    });
```

So this code will work for both the cases
`<input type="text"/>` or `<input  />` and as well as `<input type="number"/>`